# download file inside updatepanel with out PostBackTrigger

Tags: asp.net, ajax.net

I am using this part of code to download file using the onClick event for imageButton inside **UpdatePanel**, it works fine if I add the imageButton as **PostBackTrigger** for the updatePanel, is there away to do that ***with out full postback?***

```
        Dim stream As IO.Stream = Nothing
        Dim bytesToRead As Integer = 10000
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(bytesToRead - 1) {}
        Try
            Dim fileReq As Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(FileURL), Net.HttpWebRequest)
            Dim fileResp As Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(fileReq.GetResponse(), Net.HttpWebResponse)
            If fileReq.ContentLength > 0 Then fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength
            stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream()
            Dim resp = HttpContext.Current.Response
            resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & FileName & """")
            resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString())
            Dim length As Integer
            Do
                If resp.IsClientConnected Then
                    length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead)
                    resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)
                    resp.Flush()
                    buffer = New Byte(bytesToRead - 1) {}
                Else
                    length = -1
                End If
            Loop While length > 0
        Finally
            If stream IsNot Nothing Then
                stream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
```

Comment: No there is not. The only thing you could do is create a generic handler for file downloads and link to that for downloading. That works within an updatepanel.

Comment: @VDWWD , now I am using this but still the updatepanel stuck on updateprogress after downloading the file  Response.Redirect("~/report/download.ashx?url=" & url & "&fName=myFile.pdf")

Comment: Do not use server side code like response.redirect for downloading files. Just create a link: `<a target="_blank" href="/report/download.ashx?url=myfile">download</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
@HATCHA's answer on [**Asp:progress won't end anitmation when file is downloaded from ashx file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905425/aspprogress-wont-end-anitmation-when-file-is-downloaded-from-ashx-file) was great.
what @VDWWD said was wonderful , But not in my case, because I need a button to ***create the pdf*** file ***before starting the download***. which means the client side click won't be useful.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), "downloadFileExport", "javascript:window.location ='" & ResolveUrl("~/report/download.ashx?url=" & url & "&fName=" & fName) & "';", True)
```